# Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1}subsystem'

Tags: docker, configuration, wildfly, keycloak, web.xml

I am trying to use keycloak in my app. Im running keycloak on docker and using wildfly 20 as application server. I use this scrypt to start keycloak.

```
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
      container_name: keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: postgres
        DB_ADDR: host.docker.internal
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: test
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: test
      ports:
        - 8079:8080
        - 8443:8443
```

Then I added this snippet to my standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
       <secure-deployment name="pato-ejb.war">
          <realm>pato</realm>
          <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8079/auth</auth-server-url>
          <ssl-required>external</ssl-required>
          <resource>pato</resource>
          <credential name="secret">password</credential>
       </secure-deployment>
    </subsystem>
```

And security settings to my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>pato</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>user/</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

And finaly I added keycloak jars to jboss
[folder with jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR6Cs.png)

When I started standalone.bat I immediately got this error

```
11:41:14,220 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)

OPVDX001: Validation error in standalone.xml -----------------------------------
|
|  521: </subsystem>
|  522: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:4.0"/>
|  523: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
|       ^^^^ Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1}subsystem'
|
|  524:    <secure-deployment name="pato-ejb.war">
|  525:       <realm>pato</realm>
|  526:       <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8079/auth</auth-server-url>
|
| The primary underlying error message was:
| > ParseError at [row,col]:[523,9]
| > Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1}subsystem'
|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

11:41:14,223 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:395)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

11:41:14,227 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [Keycloak Downloads](https://www.keycloak.org/downloads) you'll see a section for the "Client Adapters".  This is a .zip or.tar.gz file that you extract into the Wildfly directory.  While you have the `.jar` files you need, you're missing all of the `module.xml` files.  Open up the current version and you'll see the files you need.  Additionally, there are installation files that make changes to your `standalone.xml` to enable Keycloak.  The current hierarchy looks something like:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── adapter-elytron-install.cli
│   ├── adapter-elytron-install-offline.cli
│   ├── adapter-install.cli
│   └── adapter-install-offline.cli
├── docs
│   └── licenses-keycloak
│       ├── licenses.css
│       ├── licenses.html
│       ├── licenses.xml
│       ├── licenses.xsl
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-adapter-core,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-adapter-spi,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-authz-client,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-common,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-core,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-jboss-adapter-core,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-undertow-adapter,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-undertow-adapter-spi,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-wildfly-adapter,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       ├── org.keycloak,keycloak-wildfly-elytron-oidc-adapter,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
│       └── org.keycloak,keycloak-wildfly-subsystem,12.0.1,Apache Software License 2.0.txt
└── modules
    └── system
        └── add-ons
            └── keycloak
                └── org
                    └── keycloak
                        ├── keycloak-adapter-core
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-adapter-spi
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-adapter-spi-12.0.1.jar
                        │       ├── keycloak-undertow-adapter-spi-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-adapter-subsystem
                        │   └── main
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-authz-client
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-authz-client-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-common
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-common-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-core
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-core-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-jboss-adapter-core
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-jboss-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-undertow-adapter
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-undertow-adapter-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-wildfly-adapter
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-wildfly-adapter-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        ├── keycloak-wildfly-elytron-oidc-adapter
                        │   └── main
                        │       ├── keycloak-wildfly-elytron-oidc-adapter-12.0.1.jar
                        │       └── module.xml
                        └── keycloak-wildfly-subsystem
                            └── main
                                ├── keycloak-wildfly-subsystem-12.0.1.jar
                                └── module.xml
```

I'd encourage you to install Keycloak in a local environment, outside of Docker to get a feel for how this all fits together.  [These steps](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html#installing-the-wildfly-client-adapter) walk you through the process but basically you extract the files to the Wildfly home directory and run the appropriate script in the `bin` directory.